# Full TeX Live except doc tree, source tree and fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive

I am needing TeX Live in a system with limited space. Ticking out `Install font/macro doc tree` and `Install font/macro source tree` in the installer helps a lot already. However, I wonder if there is some sensible way to exclude all the fonts from the install also. I am mainly needing fonts that do not come with TeX Live anyway. So it seems to me like a common sense to completely rely on system fonts. (Please be free to point out disadvantages of the approach.)

I know I could do minimal install and then add packages one at a time when need arises. However, I wonder if I could spare myself from the hassle, if there is a way to exclude the distributed fonts and use system fonts.

Comment: exactly my question! i hope somebody answers it.been waiting for it.
this solution may be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/52071